# Generating Non Repeating Numbers (Values) For Each <a> Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write a form that generates a non-repeating random set of numbers from range (0,9) in a group of  tags. I have written my javascript but i'm still not getting something right.

```js
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        function shuffle(array) {
            var i = array.length,
                j = 0,
                temp;

            while (i--) {
                j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
            return array;
        }

        var ranNum = shuffle([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
        $('.test').each(function(){

            $(this).html(ranNum);
        });
    })
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default test" id="1st">1</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default test" id="2nd">2</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default test" id="3rd">3</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default test" id="4th">4</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default test" id="5th">5</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-clear">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="6th">1</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="7th">2</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="8th">3</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="9th">4</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="10th">5</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-clear">Clear</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="text-success">
            <h5 class="text-success">PayCom PIN</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="PIN Number Here">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-clear">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Buy Airtime</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

what i'm getting is the array re-scheduled after every browser refresh, but with the a `href` buttons containing the entire array, not singular values across each button that are non-repeating.

Please, how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You must add `index`

```
$('.test').each(function (index, element) {
    $(element).html(ranNum[index]);
});
```

`ranNum` is your array, you must loop each **HTML element** and each **array element**.

Please, read doc: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thanks. Just what I needed. Also thanks for the doc referral.

Comment: @gbade_ always read doc when you can't do something ;) Please, select one answer as a solution for other users

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to do it might be to have your array of numbers like a 'pool' and each time you 'take' a number, it removes it from the pool. To remove the number from the pool use [`array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```js
var arrayOfAvailableNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function getNumberAtRandom() {
  var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayOfAvailableNumbers.length);
  var item = arrayOfAvailableNumbers.splice(pos, 1);
  return item[0];
}

$('.item').each(function() {
  $(this).html(getNumberAtRandom());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```